# Getting the checkboxes toggling in a GtkTreeView

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview

I am using a treeview with checkboxes. I want the user to be able to click a checkbox and it will add that item to a favourites list. But currently I cannot get the boxes to toggle at all. Here's my code:

```
def draw_columns(self,treeview):
    self.ren = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
    self.ren.connect('toggled',self.on_toggle,treeview.get_model())
    self.tvfav = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Fav',self.ren,text=7)
    for i in [self.tvfav,'andall the other columns']:
        treeview.append_column(i)

 def on_toggle(self,cell,path_str,model):
    toggle_item = model.get_value(iter,column)
    toggle_item = not toggle_item
 # This method didn't work either
 ## model[path_str][1] = not model[path_str][1]
    if toggle_item:
        #Add it to the favourite list if it isn't already
        pass
    else:
        #remove it from the favourite list
        pass
    model.set(iter,column,toggle_item)   

def __init__(self):'
    ....
    self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str,int, int, int,str, 'gboolean', str)
    self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)
    ....
```

What am I doing wrong that the boxes can't be checked? Also, how would I set the toggle when items are appended to the treeview like this:

```
if name in favourites:
    #Append to list with checkbox on
    self.liststore.append([name,x,y,z,ss,True,sss])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am confident this is not total bs, but can't test it at the moment.

First, a CellRendererToggle wouldn't take a text property. second, if you would set it anyway, you wouldn't set it to column index 7 because you only have 7 column on the liststore (and index 7 would be the eigth column).

You can see all available properties you can set for your renderer in the [reference](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcellrenderertoggle.html) under 'Properties' (note also the inherited properties). Now, to set the property for each individual cell (per row) you can specify as you did, a keyword argument. So in your TreeviewColumn you would set this:

```
# 5 is the index of bool in the liststore
gtk.TreeViewColumn('Fav',renderer,active=5)
```

Any attribute set like this is mapped to corresponding entry in the liststore. That means you can directy change it on the liststore or via a callback (on_toggle for instance).

Edit:

Maybe you have to set the [mode property](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-constants.html#gtk-cellrenderer-mode-constants) as well

Edit 2:

Here is a working example.

```
import gtk


def on_toggle(cell, path, model, *ignore):
    if path is not None:
        it = model.get_iter(path)
        model[it][0] = not model[it][0]

model = gtk.ListStore(bool)
tv = gtk.TreeView(model)

cell = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
cell.connect("toggled", on_toggle, model)
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Foo", cell, active=0)
tv.append_column(col)

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
w.show()

w.add(tv)
tv.show()

## Some initial data
model.append([True])
model.append([False])

gtk.main()
```

Comment: I still can't get the toggles to toggle, here is the code: https://github.com/JonnoFTW/5-of-Diamonds/blob/master/AoS-ServerBrowser.py , particularly around line 293, 308, 353, 356 with self.treeview.connect("button_press_event",self.serverListEvent). Can treeview and it's columns not have different handlers?

Comment: Figured it out, it was a clash between a handler for the treeview and the column. I just moved the toggle stuff inside the other listener.

Comment: Why do we need a handler for this? I mean, it is directly connect to a column of the data model that it could write to.